# How to map one child for two parents in Hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Recommend me, please, which approach to choose using Hibernate. Let's consider the following example.
I want to have three classes: **Client**, **CompanyWorker** and **PhoneNumber** and three tables: '**clients**', '**company_workers**' and '**phone_numbers**' respectively.

I want to use records in table '**phone_numbers**' for both **Client** and **CompanyWorker**. How to implement it in Hibernate and what structure of tables should be?

```
public class Client {

    private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
    
    //other code
}
```

```
public class CompanyWorker {

    private Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
    
    //other code
}
```

I thought to create separate 'phoneNumbers' tables for each classes, but didn't want to have table duplications. Also I intended to create parent class Person and to find solution using inheritance, but what if there are cases when inheritance is not suitable?